# WebStorm import organise/optimise vertically

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to make WebStorm organize imports using the built-in "Optimise Imports" functionality in a single column list?

What I get currently:

```
import { 
  FrameRateComboModule, I18nModule, MockFactory, 
  EditorPanelComponent, TimecodeUtils
} from '@acme/components';
```

What I want:

```
import { 
  FrameRateComboModule, 
  I18nModule, 
  MockFactory, 
  SegmentEditorPanelComponent, 
  TimecodeUtils 
} from '@acme/components';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting **ES6 import/export** to **Wrap Always** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Wrapping and Braces** (or **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces** if you are using typescript)